# How to extract all e-mail adresses and telephone number of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains e-mail texts :

```
 id      e-mail
 1        text_1
 2        text_2
 3        text_3
 .          .
 .          .
```

with text1 (for example)  :

```
"Gallag, Keit G" <Keit.Gallag@chart.com> 
Date: Friday, March 29, 2019 at 3:14 AM 
To: Lesl Kirch <ljkirch@action.com>
Subject: Automatic reply: News Recap, March 29, 2019 Issue of CrossTalk  

Thank you for your email. I will be out of the office Thursday, March 28th 
through Monday, April 1st. I will respond to emails on Tuesday, April 2nd. 
If this is urgent please contact lisa.chiap@chart.com or  for National 
Account question or Steph.thomp@chart.com or 309-557-1234 for 
National TeleSales 
inquiries.  
Thank you, Keith
```

I need to extract the e-mail of the sender (the first e-mail), all the e-mail adresses in the e-mail text and all the US telephone numbers and present the results like that :

```
 id   email       sender_email                   mail              telephone
 1     text_1     Keit.Gallag@chart.com    ljkirch@action.com  309-557-1234
 1     text_1     Keit.Gallag@chart.com   lisa.chiap@chart.com  ?
 1     text_1     Keit.Gallag@chart.com   Steph.thomp@chart.com  ?
 2     text_2     e-mail_sender_2               e-mail_text_2_1           Tel_text_2_1
 2     text_2     e-mail_sender_2               e-mail_text_2_2           Tel_text_2_2 
 2     text_2     e-mail_sender_2                     ?                   Tel_text_2_3
 3     text_3     e-mail_sender_3               e-mail_text_3_1           Tel_text_3_1
 4     text_4     e-mail_sender_4               e-mail_text_4_1             ?
 .       .             .                             .                       .
 .       .             .                             .                                .
```

The number of e-mails and the number of US telephone numbers vary in the e-mail text (between 0 and +inf).

Comment: Does the phone number have a consistent pattern?

Comment: Are those actual emails and phone numbers? Pretty sure Keith and Stephan don't want their names, emails, company and phone numbers posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Yusufsn, the pattern is the US phone numbers - ie xxx.xxx.xxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @jprockbelly. You're right. I just modified these data to give fictive names, mail etc. in this post...

Answer (score 4):

Using regular expression, if the email example you provided is contained in one column of the dataframe ['Data_col'], then to extract the 4 email addresses and phone number into separate columns, you can use:

```
df['Email_address']=df['Data_col'].str.findall('(\S+@\S+)')
```

And then to separate the email addresses into separate columns, use:

```
df[['Email_address_1','Email_address_2','Email_address_3','Email_address_4']]=pd.DataFrame(df['Email_address'].values.tolist())
```

For the phone number, use:

```
df['Phone_number']=df['Data_col'].str.extract('(\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4})')
```

Hope this is of more help.

Comment: thanks you for your answer, but with your solution, only the first e-mail is extracted. I want to extract all the e-mail adresses in the e-mail body...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for. At least it gives you a hint.

```
import re

info = []
for text in df["text"]:
    mail1 = re.findall("(\S+@\S+)",text)[:1]
    try:
        mail2 = re.findall("(\S+@\S+)",text)[1:]
        phone = re.findall("(\d{3}[\W]\d{3}[\W]\d{4})",text)
        mail1.insert(len(mail1),(", ".join(m for m in mail2)))
        mail1.insert(len(mail1),phone[0])
    except:
        pass
    info.append(mail1)

df[['Sender', 'Other_mails', 'Phone']] = pd.DataFrame(info)
df
```